# What is difference between android.support.v4.view.ViewPager & other

Tags: android, android-viewpager

What is  difference between `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` & other (like as `android.support.v7.view.ViewPager` & `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` ).

How can I identify & which option is best?

Comment: i cant find v7.view.ViewPager , where did u find one?

Comment: Wrong question . what is `android.support.v7.view.ViewPager ` ??

Comment: The best option depends on the classes you are using. The v4 fragments are used with the v4 ViewPager. Make sense?

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

The `android.support.` indicates the usage of the Support Library. The `v4` version is designed to be used with Android 1.6 (API level 4), `v7` with API 13. 
Some features, widgets ... are not designed to work with older android versions, therefore you have to use the support library to support older devices and android versions.

[more information](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

**BetterViewPager** is nothing but

```
    public class BetterViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public BetterViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BetterViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabledCompat(boolean enable) {
        setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(enable);
    }
}
```

`setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabledCompat(boolean)}` does some reflection that isn't needed. And was making view creation time rather large. So lets override it and make it better!